# React Native Textinput NumberOfLines property issue

Tags: react-native

version
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#numberoflines

If you look at the React Native documents, This feature is available.

this my code

[image]

**But, not working**

[image]

How can limit the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the the property doesn't set a maximum number of lines, but here's an alternative

```js
// set the max lines

const MAX_LINES = 3


// method to handle the text change
onTextFieldChange = (text) => {
   if (  text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length <= MAX_LINES ) 
   {
      this.setState({text});
   }
}


// on your textInput
<TextInput
   // properties...
   onTextChange={this.onTextInputChange}
/>
```

Comment: This answer works. Thank you.
Do you know why numberOfLines doesn't work?

Comment: @KimHanSol the property numberOfLines  sets the initial height of your text input. it doesn't limit the number of lines